# How do I enable dns addon in google container engine?

Tags: dns, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, skydns

I would like to enable the dns addon for my container engine cluster..

as described here.. http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#dns

How do I actually enable this clusterwide so that I can autodiscover my services instead of manually specifying IP addresses every time I relaunch a service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DNS is enabled by default in Google Container Engine. You should be able to use it exactly as specified in the docs.